# Firebase with architecture components

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-architecture-components

I am looking for advice on how to use android architecture components and firebase.

I am new to android programming and I've heard of architecture components and how it makes it easy for beginners to get started with android. I am using firebase realtime database as my backend.

Should I place the database calls like `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` in the repository class or its okay if I use it inside my activities and fragments?

I have searched for guidance on how to use firebase with the android architecture components but haven't found any. Any best practices on how I can use firebase with architecture components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this Firebase Blog post [Using Android Architecture Components with Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html)

Comment: You could also check this stackoverflow question here for the part about the repository 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999751/how-can-i-make-one-viewmodel-class-return-multiple-data-types-to-an-activity-or